# Is there a way to use tabs.saveAsPDF() without dialog box in firefox quantum?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my web-extensions addon I'm trying to make saving a webpage as a pdf a simple action by not popping out the 'Save As' dialog box and automatically saving the pdf to a pre-defined location.

Although the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/saveAsPDF states that the function will open a dialog, I wonder if there's a workaround to this whether it uses the tabs.saveAsPDF() or not, but still works in the Firefox 56+ web-extension environment.

Here's the firefox saveAsPDF() source for reference: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/extensions/ext-tabs.js#847

Comment: I doubt it, this is something that would be decided on the client side. generally you can't force any sort of behavior on a browser

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak: He's asking about a browser extension.

Comment: and? the user end is always going to prompt for downloads in the browser unless the user specifically sets their browser to behave otherwise. You can't force the browser to download something without a prompt even if you tell it where to go

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak the download API for extensions actually allow for saving without an dialog. It will in those cases save based on the user-preference for other types of download so if default download is set no dialog is shown ([extensions->download API->options->saveAs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The `saveAsPDF()` method currently doesn't involve the download API at all (which is also why you won't see the resulting PDF file added to the recent download list). It creates (and invokes) the dialog directly internally (line [# 849](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/extensions/ext-tabs.js#849), ibid).

Update: I have reported this to Mozilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421410) so lets see what will happen with in the future.